# Poor performance of CNN after rewriting it from tf.layers to raw tf

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

With the help of `tf.layers` module I created a simple CNN to train it on MNIST database.

First we load the data:

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
```

And then set some basic parameters, build and train the model:

```
learning_rate = 0.01
training_epochs = 10
batch_size = 100

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='InputData')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='LabelData')

with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1], name='InputReshaped')
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[4, 4], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=pool1, rate=0.25)
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=dropout1, filters=32, kernel_size=[4, 4], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    dropout2 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=pool2, rate=0.25)
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(dropout2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 32])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=256, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout3 = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.5)
    pred = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout3, units=10)

with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=pred, labels=y))

with tf.name_scope('SGD'):
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_step = optimizer.minimize(loss)

with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    acc = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    acc = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(acc, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        avg_acc = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            _, c, ac = sess.run([train_step, loss, acc], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
            avg_acc += ac / total_batch
        print("Epoch: {:04}, avg_cost = {:.9f}, avg_acc = {:.4f}".format(epoch + 1, avg_cost, avg_acc ))

    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

It works fine, performs decently and outputs the following:

```
Epoch: 0001, avg_cost = 1.032827925, avg_acc = 0.7110
Epoch: 0002, avg_cost = 0.271804677, avg_acc = 0.9180
...
Epoch: 0010, avg_cost = 0.067859485, avg_acc = 0.9790
Optimization Finished!
```

However, I want to rewrite the model without using `tf.layers`. So I changed the code in the `Model` block to the following - which I think should work almost identically as the previous one:

```
def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1, mean = 0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    with tf.name_scope('Input_L'):
        input_tsr = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1], name='InputReshaped')
    with tf.name_scope('Conv1_L'):
        W_conv1 = weight_variable([4, 4, 1, 32])
        b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
        conv1 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(input_tsr, W_conv1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), b_conv1)
        h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)
        h_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv1, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        dropout1 = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool1, 0.75)
    with tf.name_scope('Conv2_L'):
        W_conv2 = weight_variable([4, 4, 32, 32])
        b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])
        conv2 = tf.add(tf.nn.conv2d(dropout1, W_conv2, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'), b_conv2)
        h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)
        h_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv2, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        dropout2 = tf.nn.dropout(h_pool2, 0.75)
    with tf.name_scope('Dense_L'):
        W_dense = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 32, 256])
        b_dense = bias_variable([256])
        flat_tsr = tf.reshape(dropout2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 32])
        dense = tf.add(tf.matmul(flat_tsr, W_dense), b_dense)
        h_dense =  tf.nn.relu(dense)
        dropout3 = tf.nn.dropout(h_dense, 0.5)
    with tf.name_scope('Output_L'):
        W_out = weight_variable([256, 10])
        b_out = bias_variable([10])
        pred = tf.add(tf.matmul(dropout3, W_out), b_out)
```

Unfortunately it performs very poorly and can't get the accuracy above `0.12` which I think means that the model is guessing the right answer.

```
Epoch: 0001, avg_cost = 22.226242821, avg_acc = 0.1106
Epoch: 0002, avg_cost = 2.301470806, avg_acc = 0.1123
...
Epoch: 0010, avg_cost = 2.301233784, avg_acc = 0.1123
Optimization Finished!
```

Why does the second model does not learn properly? Can you point out where is the difference between the first model and the second one (except weights and biases initialization)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is mentioned in the documentation, but for layers in the `tf.layers` submodule, variable initializers default to `glorot_uniform_initializer` when `None` are provided.

If you replace your weight definition accordingly, you should get closer to your previous results.

Comment: In fact it solves the problem. I doubted that initial values might have such influance on the performance. Now I think that combination of initial values and low learning rate made the algorithm stuck in some local minimum.